# Angular 5 + i18n for select html tag

Tags: internationalization, angular5

Hi I need to use i18n in Angular 5 for below tag.

```
<select name="colCaseType" type="string" [(ngModel)]="colCaseType" #select4>
    <option *ngFor="let level of caseType" [ngValue]="level.caseStatus" i18n>
    {{level.caseStatus | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

ts

```
public caseType: Array<Object> = [
    {caseStatus: 'OPEN'},
    {caseStatus: 'CLOSED'},
    {caseStatus: 'RISK ACCEPTED'},
    {caseStatus: 'ALL'}
];
```

How to implement Internationalization for this?

Comment: <select name="colCaseType" type="string" [(ngModel)]="colCaseType" #select4>
  <option *ngFor="let level of caseType" [ngValue]="level.caseStatus" i18n>{{level.caseStatus | translate}}</option>
</select>

Comment: please edit your question and move your comment inside the question

Answer (score -1):

This is angular internationalization.
visit https://angular.io/guide/i18n